# Consequences of cascade drop on sequences/functions/views

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating some data to another server while dropping all sequences/functions/views. When I try to do simply

`DROP VIEW | SEQUENCE | FUNCTION | AGGREGATE` without `CASCADE`, errors are thrown to indicate dependencies. The goal is that if no data (=tables?) will be affected by using `CASCADE`, then I can use it.

**Assumption**: if no table is dependent on views/functions/sequences, then no table will be affected by using `CASCADE`.

Then I guess using `CASCADE` for views will be fine since they always depend on some base tables.

For functions and sequences I am not very sure. I haven't written that many of sql functions myself and I don't know if the data in a table are generated by some function, whether it means the table depends on the function.

For sequences, it seems that a sequence will be generated automatically by postgres if I use `serial` as column type. My first guess would be that in this case, the table that is using `serial` depends on the sequence. However, by testing on a dummy database on my laptop, I found that the data seems to be unaffected. (I just use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME` after dropping the sequence)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite certain that no table would be dropped if you remove views, sequences and functions with the `CASCADE` option.

But parts of a table may vanish:

- Indexes, triggers, rules, column defaults, check constraints and in PostgreSQL v12 generated columns may vanish if you drop the functions and operators used in them.
- Column defaults will vanish with the sequences used in them.

Dropping views should not affect tables at all.

Disclaimer: I have probably forgotten one or two cases.

Why don't you just selectively dump the parts of the database that you need with the `-l` and `-L` options of `pg_restore`?

Comment: Does that mean if I don't specify my column value of `serial` type, it will be `NULL`? But in my case the column using `serial` also has the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, so will it still have a default value at all?

Comment: By the way, I didn't find the option `-l` or `-L` in the [documentation of pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: No, the primary key column won't have a default value then. Sorry about the `-l`, I meant `pg_restore` (fixed in the answer).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know `-l` and `-L` can be that useful. However, actually I am migrating the whole cluster, and there are too many datasets to inspect and filter manually. That's why I look for a more automatic solution (which yet probably does not lead to the best result)